# Downscaling of remote desktop terminal control using MSTSCLib

Tags: c#, wpf, scaling, remote-desktop, windowsformshost

I'm currently using the MSTSCLib (referenced through Microsoft Terminal Services) to integrate a remote desktop session to a WPF application. In detail, an instance of `AxMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting` is hosted within a `WindowsFormsHost`, which in turn is used in a WPF project.

Works perfectly well, the problem is that I'd like to scale down the whole remote desktop view. For example, if the remote PC's desktop resolution is 1024x768, I'd like the remote desktop control in my WPF app to be 4 times smaller and take only 25% of that space (just like downscaling an image).

Any ideas of how that could be achieved? Need not be using MSTSCLib, its just the only way I managed to get the remote session to work...

(By the way, the remote session is used "watch only", so its not necessary to interact with the remote machine - maybe there is a way to just capture the remote machine's screen and share that as video stream?)